# How to increase tappable area of navigationBarItem in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have this code for my `view`

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            List{
                ForEach(0...5, id: \.self) { note in
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        Text("title")
                        Text("subtitle")
                            .font(.subheadline)
                            .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationBarItems(trailing: resetButton)
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Notes"))
        }
    }

    var resetButton: some View {
        Button(action: {
            print("reset")
        }) {
            Image(systemName: "arrow.clockwise")
        }
        .background(Color.yellow)
    }
}
```

`resetButton` looks like this:
[image]

When I am tapping the `resetButton`, it seems like only the yellow area responds to touches.

How do I make tappable area of this button bigger? (Make it behave like a normal `UIBarButtonItem`)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can change the frame of the `view` **inside** the button:

```
var resetButton: some View {
    Button(action: {
        print("reset")
    }) {
        Image(systemName: "arrow.clockwise")
        .frame(width: 44, height: 44) // Or any other size you like
    }
    .background(Color.yellow)
}
```

Comment: Thanks. However this does not solve the problem. Even though yellow area become bigger corner of it are still not responding to touches. Moreover image becomes even more offset to the left

Comment: Oh sorry my bad. I missed a line as I typed it by hand. I changed the answer.

Comment: Can't believe there are no examples from Apple on how this is supposed to be done. The accepted answer works (thanks @MojtabaHosseini), but it just feels like more work than it should have to be.

Answer (score 4):

[This blog post](https://alejandromp.com/blog/playing-with-swiftui-buttons/) pointed me in the right direction, I needed to add some padding directly to the Image.

[image]

```swift
Button(action: {
    // Triggered code
}) {
    Image(systemName: "plus")
        .font(.system(size: 22, weight: .regular))
        .padding(.vertical)
        .padding(.leading, 60)
}
.background(Color.red) // Not needed
```